# pull down data from firebase specific to the user that is logged in

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Do you know why this error is occurring:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.keepSynced(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Is it because I am not accessing the data at the right level?

```
public class contacts extends Fragment {

    EditText contactName, contactPhone;
    Button upload;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    String userId;
    contact Contact;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    FirebaseUser user;
    TextView dataReceived;
    Activity context;







    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts, container, false);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        contactName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.nameReg);
        contactPhone = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.phoneReg);
        upload = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userId = user.getUid();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("phone").child(userId);


        Contact = new contact();
        dataReceived = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.datarecieved);




        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        getValues();
                        databaseReference.child("contact").push().setValue(Contact);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Inserted.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Failed" + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }


    private void getValues(){
        Contact.setContactName(contactName.getText().toString());
        Contact.setContactPhone(contactPhone.getText().toString());

    }

}
```

And this is how I am pulling down the data:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
user= auth.getCurrentUser();
 databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("phone").child(user.getUid());
        options1 = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<contact>().setQuery(databaseReference1,contact.class).build();
        adapter1 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<contact, contactAdapter>(options1) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final contactAdapter holder, final int position, @NonNull contact model) {
                holder.contactName.setText(model.getContactName());
                holder.contactPhone.setText(model.getContactPhone());
                SharedPreferences prefs =  Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String check_state = prefs.getString( "state", "default");
                holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            holder.chk.setChecked(true);
                            for (int i = 0; i < adapter1.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                if (adapter1.getItem(i).isSelected(true)) {
                                    number = ((TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactPhone)).getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Inserted....." + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("state", "true"+String.valueOf(position));
                            editor.apply();
                            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }else {
                            holder.chk.setChecked(false);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("state", "false"+String.valueOf(position));
                            editor.apply();
                            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public contactAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new contactAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.item_contacts, parent, false));

            }
        };
```

[image]

Just underneath phone is the user id.

```
  Process: com.example.carcrashdetection, PID: 16924
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.keepSynced(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.carcrashdetection.Home.onActivityCreated(Home.java:92)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2614)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2076)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1821)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Add.a screenshot of your database.

Comment: I added the screenshot there.

Comment: okay check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is the database:

```
Phone
|
|---------userID
          -------name:"..."
          -------phone:"..."
```

And assuming that you are logged in:

```
public class contacts extends Fragment {

......

//add this

private FirebaseAuth auth;
private FirebaseUser currentUser;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
         currentUser= auth.getCurrentUser();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts, container, false);
    }
```

Now your database like this:

```
databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("phone").child(currentUser.getUid());
```

**Update**

**Save the data like I told you according to the UID of the user:**

And when you did that, read like this instead of the RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public void readDataFromPhones(){

ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      //only the current user can read the data in his/her node
       String name = dataSnapshot.child("contactName").getValue(String.class);
       String phone = dataSnapshot.child("contactPhone").getValue(String.class);



    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // log error
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }
};
databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(listener);



}
```

Comment: I think its just a key that I generate I dont think its userID how to i make the key the userID??

Comment: instead of the random key, use the `currentUser.getUid();`

Comment: so instead of generating a key like this ` key= databaseReference.push().getKey();` I use the user id instead?

Comment: ahh okay ill try now and let you know.!!

Comment: If you want that the user read his/her own data, why do you need a list?

Comment: I dont really know what you mean.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what are you aiming for, what result do you want?

Comment: I want users to upload contacts to firebase and then pulled down into my app .as soon as they are uploaded. The contacts that I want shown to the user should only be the ones that they uploaded

Comment: do I not need the adapter cause I'm using a recycler view

Comment: no need for a recycler view if you are pulling 2 values per user.

Comment: Im pulling lots of different contact per user. A user can have many contacts. sorry i probably didnt explain it right the first time.

Comment: its okay pull the data and save them in a list object, and then use a regular listView you can find plenty of tutorials here on the site.

Comment: im trying to push it up using user id but each item just overrides to other

Comment: Your question was solved for reading the data per logged in user, other than that I suggest you ask new question to avoid extended discussion.

Comment: Okay one last thing since it has to do with my previous question and ive been trying to get this working for so long. I have updated my question  and I am now able to upload data under the current users id but when I am trying to pull the data down I get the error mentioned. is it because i'm not accessing the data at the right level? I have also included the new structure of my database and underneath phone is the userid.

Comment: The error is because you call keep synced on a null database reference in your app.

Comment: i know yeah but i dont know why its null :(

Comment: Maybe because you didn't initialize it. ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRef().child(,....)......

Comment: I have like this `databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("phone").child(user.getUid());`

Comment: The error says in an activity called `Home`

Comment: ah its cause i had this `databaseReference1.keepSynced(true);` I got rid of it now it works. thanks for the help.